# Weird line bug at the top of images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have been working on a website for the last couple days. I uploaded it just now and have no idea why I'm getting little lines at the peak of images on scroll events?

Any idea how solve this?

The website is http://oliverkle.in

Essentially i have the images with an altered speed using JQuery.
I'll show the basis of an image and its HTML:

```
<div class="mountains1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.mountains1 {
  background: url(../img/mountains1.png) repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 13;
}
```

and JavaScript:

```
var parallax = function(){
  var $scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
  var $scrollX = $(window).scrollLeft();
  $('.mountains1'  ).css('top', '1640' -($scrollY * 1) + 'px');
}

$(document).ready(function(){parallax();});
$(window).scroll(function(){parallax();});
```

ps. I'm using safari, when the bug occurs, it doesn't happen in chrome.

When i use the ceil() or round() method for some reason it breaks it?

Here are the changes i made in response to Leo

```
var parallax = function(){
var $scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
var $scrollX = $(window).scrollLeft();
var $scrollYint = Math.round($scrollY);
$('.cloudback'  ).css('top', '-375' -($scrollYint * 0.4) + 'px');

$('.mountains1'  ).css('top', '1640' -($scrollYint * 1) + 'px');
$('.mountains2'  ).css('top', '1200'-($scrollYint * 0.75) + 'px');
$('.mountains3'  ).css('top', '720'-($scrollYint * 0.3) + 'px');

$('.navbar2'  ).css('top', '1700' -($scrollYint * 0.7) + 'px');

$('.forest1'  ).css('top', '3100' -($scrollYint * 0.8) + 'px');
$('.forest2'  ).css('top', '2600'-($scrollYint * 0.6) + 'px');
$('.forest3'  ).css('top', '2100'-($scrollYint * 0.4) + 'px');

$('.navbar3'  ).css('top', '3600' -($scrollYint * 0.8) + 'px');

//$('.grass1'  ).css('top', '5250' -($scrollY * 0.8) + 'px');
//$('.grass2'  ).css('top', '4500'-($scrollY * 0.6) + 'px');
//$('.grass3'  ).css('top', '3750'-($scrollY * 0.4) + 'px');

//$('.navbar4'  ).css('top', '5500' -($scrollY * 0.8) + 'px');
```

}

Comment: Please do include your code.  Links die over time, and it loses the context of your question.

Comment: Don't know where do you got this—"Don't think there is any need putting up code for now"—from, but this is not the best way to ask for help with an issue. Learn how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example. If you do not show any effort in debugging the code yourself and formulating a problem statement, then it is difficult to encourage members of the community to help.

Comment: What code would you like me to include? I don't actually know what is causing it because its a safari thing. But i can't really add the entirety of the code for the site?

Comment: Sorry Terry, i have tried messing with he images but i literally have no idea what it is. Any recommendations of what code snippets i could add? Thanks

Comment: Then show the minimal code that is required to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Added an example of an image that suffers the bug Terry, any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the background-repeat?

Comment: Will give that a shot now mhu!

Comment: Didn't fix the issue, any other ideas? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look at your code and see you are using javascript to work out the top value for your absolutely positioned images. The line appears above the images when the top value works out to a value with a decimal place. e.g. `top: 1642.4px;` rather then `top:1643px`.

So, you need to update your parallax function to round the value of top for your images to avoid getting a result with a decimal place.

Comment: Its up in the question above :) ^

Comment: Just realised i use the round function completely wrong, Let me test it again

Comment: Updated and and added to the website (live) still seeing the lines, Let me know if i have made a stupid mistake in rounding, aha!

Comment: You are rounding in wrong place. The values in your css are still decimals. You need to do it like this:         $('.mountains1'  ).css('top', '1640' -(Math.round($scrollY * 0.75)) + 'px');